# Binary search using recursion without number of elements in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm writing a program that uses binary search via recursion for integers entered by the user with 0 being the last integer entered. I am assuming the user will enter them in increasing order and that they will not enter more than 10 integers. I've gotten it to work, but it always returns that the number searched for is in the series when it's not. Example:

```
Numbers entered: 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
Number to search for: 9
9 is in the series
```

I imagine it has something to do with not knowing the size of the array other than that it's maximum is 10, but I don't want to ask for the number of elements the user wants. How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_m(int a[], int i, int m)

{ 
    int mid;

    if (first>last) {
        return -1;
    }
    mid=(first+last)/2;
    if (a[mid]>m) {
        find_m(a, first, mid-1, m);
    }
    else if (a[mid]<m) {
        find_m(a, first, mid+1, m);
    }
    else {
        return mid;
    }

}


int main()

{
    int a[10], i, m, first, mid, last, found;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf ("Please enter integers (no more than 10 numbers) in increasing order with a 0 as the last number\n"); 
        scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
        if (a[i]==0) {
            break;
        }
    }   

    printf ("Now enter a number you would like to find in the series\n");
    scanf ("%d", m); 

    found=find_m(a, m, 0, i-1);

    if (found==1) {
        printf ("%d is not in the series\n", m);
    }
    else {
        printf ("%d is in the series\n", m);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You do know the size of the array. It is `i`.

Comment: Binary search needs to know the _length_ of the array.  This array is terminated with a sentinel `0`.  To find the array length, each element needs to be checked against 0.  Might as well also check each element for the sought after number too and skip this whole recursion bit.  If the length is in `i`, then no need for the terminating `0`.

Comment: BTW `find_m(a, first, mid-1, m);` --> `return find_m(a, first, mid-1, m);`, `if (found==1) {` --> `if (found == -1) {`

Comment: `scanf ("%d", m);` --> `scanf ("%d", &m); `

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a[mid]>m) {
    find_m(a, first, mid-1, m);
}
else if (a[mid]<m) {
    find_m(a, first, mid+1, m);
}
else {
    return mid;
}
```

In the above code, you're only returning a value in 1 out of the 3 possible branches of that if/else if/else block and then the function ends. So you're getting undefined behaviour for those other 2. You'll need to `return` the results you get from your calls to `find_m()`, although by the looks of it `found` ultimately becomes the position within the array of that value not just 1.